# How to Render Select Field using Redux Form and Semantic UI

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux, semantic-ui, redux-form

I use the following codes to render the select field. The field shows correctly with the options, but it cannot select the value. I use redux form and semantic UI react. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Form} from "semantic-ui-react";

const RenderFieldSelect = field => (
  <Form.Select
    {...field.input}
    label={field.label}
    options={field.options}
    placeholder={field.placeholder}
    fluid
  />
);

export default RenderFieldSelect



import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import { Form} from "semantic-ui-react";
import RenderFieldInput from '../formElements/Input';
import RenderFieldSelect from '../formElements/Select';
import {YES_NO} from '../formElements/SelectOptions';

class TestAttributes extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form.Group widths="equal">
                    <Field name="test1" component={RenderFieldInput} label="test1"/>
                    <Field name="test2" component={RenderFieldInput} label="test2"/>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group widths="equal">
                    <Field name="test3" component={RenderFieldSelect} label="test3" options={YES_NO}/>
                    <Field name="test4" component={RenderFieldInput} label="test4"/>
                </Form.Group>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default TestAttributes;


export const YES_NO = [
                    { text: "Yes", value: "Yes" },
                    { text: "No", value: "No"}
                  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's in field.input? From [react semantic ui docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/#auto-controlled-state):

> If you add a value prop or an open prop, the Dropdown delegates
>   control for that one prop to your value. The other props remain auto
>   controlled.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my posting. I use Field and pass the RenderFieldSelect to the component. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

need to add

```
onChange={(e, { value }) => field.input.onChange(value)}
```

Hope this can help others have the same confusion.